# spring security - role based access

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I have implemented spring security for my webapp.

I want to configure role based access. Only users with the role "ROLE_ADMIN" should be abeĺe to login.

I added the model "Role" and added a table in my database.
However users with the role "ROLE_USER" are still able to login.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
    try {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Edit: complete spring security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = UserDetailsServiceImpl.class)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
    try {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    return authProvider;
}

@Autowired
public void globalSecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    try {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` ? Also hasRole will prefix the provided string with "ROLE_"

from doc:

*the role to require (i.e. USER, ADMIN, etc). Note, it should not start with "ROLE_" as this is automatically inserted.*

example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleWebSecureJdbcApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(SampleWebSecureJdbcApplication.class).run(args);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    protected static class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                    .authorizeRequests()    
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()    
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")  
                    .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()    
                    .and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout().permitAll();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(this.dataSource);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a Role based access where after the login admin user will be directed to the admin homepage and normal user will be redirected to the user homepage.

Below is my SecurityConfiguration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {

        final String sqlUserName = "select email, password, active from user where email=?";
        final String sqlAuthorities= "select u.email, r.role from user u inner join user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?";

        auth.
                jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(sqlUserName)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(sqlAuthorities)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.   authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/static.css/**", "/js/**", "/static.images/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user").hasAuthority("USER")
                .antMatchers("/home").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/loginroute",true)
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/static.css/**", "/js/**", "/static.images/**");
    }

}
```

**.defaultSuccessUrl("/loginroute",true)** will redirect to the /loginroute controller. Below is the controller methods.

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/loginroute",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sample(){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
        String rolevalue = null;
        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
           rolevalue = role.getRole();
        }
        System.out.println(user.getRoles().contains("role"));
        if(rolevalue.equals("ADMIN"))
            return "redirect:home";
        else if(rolevalue.equals("USER"))
            return "redirect:user";
        return "User does not have permission";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
        modelAndView.addObject("userName", "Welcome " + user.getName() + " " + user.getLastName() + " (" + user.getEmail() + ")");
        modelAndView.addObject("adminMessage","Content Available Only for Users with Admin Role");
        modelAndView.setViewName("home");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView userhome(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
        modelAndView.addObject("userName", "Welcome user: " + user.getName() + " " + user.getLastName() + " (" + user.getEmail() + ")");
        modelAndView.addObject("userMessage","Content Available Only for Users with User Role");
        modelAndView.setViewName("user");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```